# The redundancy of package in intent class

Tags: android, android-intent, package

In the android source code for the Intent class [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java) , I noticed that there are two private fields namely `private String mPackage` and `private ComponentName mComponent`. However `ComponentName` already has its own field `private String mPackage` [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9a7debe5857ffc7c71cfc4082b1b6d72a5cf81cd/core/java/android/content/ComponentName.java). Why do we then have this redundancy in the Intent class? Or are the two fields which have the same names `mPackage` actually different?

Answer (score 0):

Those two package names are technically different.

When creating a new Android project in Eclipse, or Android Studio, the new project wizard makes it like there is only one package name, but in actuality, it takes the package name you give it and makes two identical package names out of it, one package name for the application and one package for the class.

In other words, enter the package name `com.example.myapplication` into the new project wizard, and the resulting class will be located at `/com/example/myapplication/com/example/myapplication/MainActivity.class`

(knowing that will make it easier for you call it as an explicit intent from a different application)

And of course, nothing says you can't change the class package name, or add new class package names, while keeping the original application package name the same as the original one, so then, you could end up with a location like this one for instance:

`/com/example/myapplication/com/newcompanyname/newconcept/MainActivity.class`